# ConstraintEnd not working on relative layout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to set up a constraintEnd on my relative layout but no matter what I place there, only the constraintStart works whereas the end one seems to be ignored. What could be amiss?
This is the part:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/intrusion_component_root"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="148dp"
   android:clipChildren="false"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
   android:duplicateParentState="true"
   android:focusable="true">

<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/rl_button_shadow"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_background"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_icon_total_connection"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_icon_partial_connection"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/v_background">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_shadow"
           style="@style/Detail"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:background="@drawable/shadow_background"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:paddingStart="6dp"
           android:paddingEnd="6dp"
           android:translationZ="8dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I assume you have this wrapped in a ConstraintLayout? What does that look like?

Comment: @Nickel I added it